# Arrange positioning logo on background image

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to positioning  three logo on the background image like in this picture.

[image]

Unfortunately, it becomes like this image

[image]

What should I do to make it work?

Code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
         body: Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 image: DecorationImage(
                     image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg_splash.jpg"),
                     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                 ),
             ),
             child: Row(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: < Widget > [
                     Container(
                         child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo_splash.jpg",
                             height: 100, width: 100, scale: 3.5
                             // fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                         ),
                     ),
                     Container(
                         child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo_splash.jpg",
                             height: 100, width: 100, scale: 3.5
                             // fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                         ),
                     ),
                 ]),
         ),
     );
 }
```

Comment: Unable to understand the question .Kindly elaborate this.

Comment: I've edit my question..

Comment: mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,  Give in row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/bg_splash.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child:
            Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
          Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo_splash.jpg",
                      height: 100, width: 100, scale: 3.5
                      // fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo_splash.jpg",
                      height: 100, width: 100, scale: 3.5
                      // fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      ),
                ),
              ]),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo_splash.jpg",
                height: 100, width: 100, scale: 3.5
                // fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Column allows you to arrange them above and below, and then Row with

```
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
```

to get the desired spacing.